# get max of two columns (one column stores the date and other stores the time)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, max

*tableABC* has separate date and time columns:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| AccountID | userID |   date    | timestamp |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|       123 |      1 | 29-MAR-13 |     21005 |
|       123 |      1 | 29-MAR-13 |     11005 |
|       123 |      1 | 23-MAR-13 |     21005 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need the max of date column and timestamp column. The query I wrote only does the max of date and not the timestamp:

```
select * 
from tableABC rn 
where userID = '1'  
    and accountID = '123'
    and date =
    (
        select max(date) MaxDate 
        from tableABC b 
        where b.userID = rn.userID
            and b.accountID = rn.accountID
    );
```

Comment: Do you only want the most recent row for a single user/account, not the most recent row for each user/account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `order by`:

```
select *
from (select *
      from tableABC
      order by "date" desc, "timestamp" desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

If you are trying to get the maximum for each accountID/userID combination, then use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by userId, accountId order by "date" desc, "timestamp" desc) as seqnum
      from tableABC
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Notice Ed Gibbs' answer re: reserved / special words. This query does work for a single user: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c85a3/1

Comment: @Alkini . . . I'm aware of the reserved words.  I was just using the same format as in the original question.  Presumably, the original question modified the field names from the actual names for the posting, because that original query would not run.

Comment: Right; I meant to direct that at jero and back you up that your query was fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Oracle won't let you name a column `DATE` unless you surround the column name with double quotes, but I'd recommend just not naming it `DATE` - you'll avoid all kinds of trouble.

Oracle doesn't mind if a column is named `TIMESTAMP`, but that's still a "special" Oracle word so again I'd recommend not doing it. Oracle won't be confused but anyone reading your code will be.

Let's say the columns are named `my_date` and `my_timestamp`. To query the top date/timestamp for all users do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    AccountID,
    userID,
    my_date,
    my_timestamp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY AccountID, UserID
      ORDER BY my_date DESC, my_timestamp DESC) AS DateTimestampRank
  FROM TableABC
) WHERE DateTimeStampRank = 1
```

If you want a query for just one user, the answer from @GordonLinoff is the one to use.

Comment: Add my_timestamp to the ORDER BY too.

Comment: this is just a reference not the actual table name or column name.

Comment: And add FROM tableABC to the inner select; then it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c85a3/3

Comment: To demonstrate what it does with multiple users: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f8cc/1

Comment: Thanks yet again @Alkini and sorry all for such a sloppy post. I normally test first, but I do so many analytic queries nowadays that I got cocky. Lesson learned! Also, many thanks to those who up-voted despite the flaws :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you order by date, and then time, and take the top row?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCOUNTID,USERID,MAX(DATE1),MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM tableABC
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID,USERID,DATE1;
```